# Problem with search script I can't take a good property from navbar to searchcomponent in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have issue with my search script in Vue.js. I can't take property from navbar component to search component. Search component is connected with Search.vue file but it only has appeal to search component.

```
<template>
<div>
    <Navbar></Navbar>
    <div class="container"> 
        <br> 
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8"> 
                <div v-if="showsearch == true">
                <div v-for="post in posts.data" :key="post.id">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">{{post.title}}</div>
                        <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <div id="description">{{post.description}}</div>
                            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" v-if="post.source_url !== null && post.source_url !== undefined">
                                <iframe id="source_url" class="embed-responsive-item" :src="post.source_url + '?showinfo=0'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen/>
                            </div>
                            <div v-if="post.file_name !== null && post.file_name !== 'undefined'">
                                <img id="file_name" class="img-responsive" :src="'images/' + post.file_name"/>
                            </div>
                            <div id="author">Wrzucony przez: {{post.author}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>  
                </div>
                <pagination :meta_data="meta_data" v-on:next="fetchSearch"></pagination>  
                <div v-if="showsearch == false"></div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import Pagination from '/resources/js/components/Pagination'
import Navbar from '/resources/js/components/Navbar'

export default {
    data(){
        return {
            posts: [],
            post: {
                id: '',
                title: '',
                description: '',
                author: '',
                source_url: '',
                file_name: '',
            },
            meta_data: {
                last_page: null,
                current_page: 1,
                prev_page_url: null
            },
            props: ['search'],
            showsearch: false,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchSearch();
    },
    components: {
        Pagination,
        Navbar
    },
    methods: {
        fetchSearch(page = 1){
            axios.get('/api/post/search/' + this.props.search + '?page=' + page)
            .then(res => {
                this.posts = res.data;
                this.search = res.data.search;
                this.showsearch = true;
                this.meta_data.last_page = res.data.last_page;
                this.meta_data.current_page = res.data.current_page;
                this.meta_data.prev_page_url = res.data.prev_page_url; 
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        },      
    },
}
</script>
```

```
<template>
  <div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <nuxt-link to="/" class="navbar-brand nav-link">PanZiemniak</nuxt-link>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <nuxt-link to="/create" class="nav-link">Dodaj Ziemniaka</nuxt-link>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-right" action="/search" method="GET">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Podaj tytuł" aria-label="search" id="search" name="search" v-model="search">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Wyszukaj</button>
        </form>
    </nav>
    <nuxt/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: ['search'],
  data(){
    return{
      search: '',
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

My output in network:

```
URL Request:http://localhost/api/post/search/undefined?page=1
Method request:GET
Code: 200
```

Comment: if you want to pass data from a parent to a child, use props, if you want data to be local to the component, use data. Don't use both with the same name (search) as this will cause conflicts. To pass props down to a child, you need to set the key/value on the component like `<Navbar :search="search" />`. You'll probably want to change the data inside the parent component to be `search: ''` rather than `props: ['search']` too

Comment: So I have to change `<Navbar></Navbar>` to `<Navbar :meta_search="meta_search"></Navbar>`, on SearchComponent.vue and in Navbar.vue I should stay simply `export default {
  props: ['meta_search'],
}` , but in SearchComponent change inside `data(){ return{ meta_search: { search: '', }}}` and in `axios.get('/api/post/search/' + this.props.search + '?page=' + page)` change `this.props.search` on `search` and inside axios `this.search = res.data.search;` change for `this.meta_search.search = res.data.search;` but when I did it I got  Request `/api/post/search/[object HTMLInputElement]?page=1`